# Write-only buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp, advising-functions, defadvice

I would like to imitate the way how most consoles work in a buffer, is there any way to do that? I.e. only allow appending text to the buffer, but not deleting?

Probably I could disable or advise some built-in functions which delete characters, but I'm afraid this isn't a very scalable solution... I could miss some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, you can set the read-only text-property.  Or more simply you can set the `buffer-read-only` variable and then write a few commands that override it.  For example (guaranteed 100% untested code ahead):

```
(defun append-only-s-i-c ()
  (let ((inhibit-read-only (eobp)))
    (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))

(defvar append-only-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [remap self-insert-command] 'append-only-s-i-c)
    map))

(define-derived-mode append-only-mode nil "Append-Only"
  "Here's the doc."
  (set (make-local-variable 'buffer-read-only) t))
```

As demonstrated by this example, the read-only-ness of text can be overriden by a command, so even the `read-only` text-property won't guarantee 100% that the text will never be modified, but fairly few commands override the read-only information, so it should not be a serious problem in practice.

Another approach would be to use `before-change-functions` and signal an error from there if the modification takes place before EOB.  Might be a better approach:

```
(defun append-only-b-c-f (beg end)
  (if (< beg (point-max)) (error "Can't modify text: append-only!")))

(define-derived-mode append-only-mode nil "Append-Only"
  "Here's the doc."
  (add-hook 'before-change-functions #'append-only-b-c-f nil 'local))
```

Comment: Indeed, it's a problem.  FWIW, wid-edit.el uses the following hack to work around it: they `(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'widget-add-change nil t)` just before signalling the error, where `widget-add-change` re-adds the function to the `before-change-functions` hook.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to set the `read-only` property on text as it is inserted, see [special properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html)